# Accessing memory space / registers on externally connected devices through software

Tags: usb, external

This question is a bit vague, and I apologzie for that, but a fairly vague answer will do :)
How do people typically access memory adresses of external devices (say, connected to a PC through USB, or even just say, a multipurpose microcontroller)? I'm wondering how software is able to find address to write to registers or EEPROM space.

For example if I want to write a value to register 0x1234, does software just send this information (the register and the value to be written) to some sort of driver that "talks" to the device and takes care of the value change through hardware?
Is implementation of this functionality mostly a hardware endeavor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use as an example a fairly common USB peripheral controller that is based on an 8-bit 8051 microcontroller core.  One side of it attaches to the USB host controller on a desktop computer.  The other end goes to a USB device controller that presents itself as a FIFO endpoint to the host.

Some 8051 firmware will be required to initialize the device side.  A class driver will be required on the host side.  Once those are in place, the application developer will have a device name on the host side which may be opened for read/write.  Sometimes a vendor will provide a library to perform device specific tasks and isolate the user from the raw device.  Often a Windows DLL is available to hide the low level I/O and present device operations as function calls.

Additional 8051 firmware monitors the FIFO from device end and interprets messages sent from the host application or DLL then takes actions.  These actions may be low level such as read/write from a memory location or register.  They may be high level such as setting the PWM value of a programmable counter array.

So your hypothetical description of a write to register 0x1234 is not far from how it is often implemented.